# python convert bit hex to binary

Tags: python, binary, hex, encode

ok, im fairly new to python but not programming, I know php, C, bash, etc...  My question is:
   How do I convert `data = "b'\x16'" to binary "0001 0110"` ?? 
im trying to read the response from an esc printer from DLE

```
    x = 1
    while x:
       time.sleep(3)
       ser.write("\x10\x04\x01".encode())
       bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
       data = ser.read(bytesToRead)
       while data:
          print(data)
          data = ""
```

all that ends up printing is: **b'\x16'**  i assume hex but a simple hex to bin is not working because of the b?

Comment: Is your `while data:` in the wrong place? It's kind of useless where it's at.

Comment: its just for testing results the same

Comment: print(bin(int.from_bytes(data, byteorder="big")).strip('0b')) something like that? but that does not look right either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you get back is a `bytes` object. (think: raw array of bytes) You can get the number itself from the first byte via `data[0]`. That will give you `0x16` as an `int`, which you can convert however you want.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, i did not realize data was being returned as an array... so something like  `print(bin(data[0]).strip('0b'))`

Comment: @JeffreyWorsley You don't want that - `'0b010'.strip('0b') == '1'`. Maybe `bin(data[0])[2:]` instead.